# Vote question closure up or down

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I would like the Stack Exchange sites to provide a way for members to respectfully agree or disagree with the closing of a question, particularly if it is marked as "off topic" or "duplicate". Over the years I have obtained a great deal of very useful information from questions that are closed, and in most of those cases I disagree with the decision to close it. I believe this will benefit the Stack Exchange communities in two important ways:

1. The body of subject matter that is deemed "on topic" is controlled by a very small group of elite members. Considering (a) the number of upvotes on closed questions, and (b) the number of closed questions that appear as top-ranking results in Google searches, it seems evident that the communities using these sites do not entirely share the views of the elite. The upvote/downvote on question closure would allow the community to respectfully participate in defining the bounds of subject matter for each Stack Exchange site.
2. The definition of "duplicate" is much more subjective than its boolean nature suggests. From one person's perspective, two similar questions may seem incontrovertibly identical, because that person finds no additional value in the subtle differences between them. But a second person may find those same two questions to be distinct in some important way, for example if one of the questions emphasizes an aspect of the issue that the other does not (and contains helpful points on that aspect). These subtle distinctions may be difficult for a moderator to see, especially since the moderator is not reading the question with the goal of solving a problem.

If this feature were implemented, it might be prudent to restrict the new upvote/downvote on question closure to members with a certain reputation level, since newer members may not have enough experience in the community to understand its values and goals. The moderators can still have the final say about closing questions, but should be notified when any of their closures has received a very large number of contradictory downvotes. They can still say "well people just don't get it," but at least they should know that the community strongly favors a different perspective.

Comment: If you have the power to vote to close a question then you also get to vote to reopen it. How does your proposal differ from voting to reopen? Why does voting to reopen not work and why is this superior to it?

Comment: You do get a say.  Once you earn it and get 3K rep.  Until then, you're not considered to have invested enough in the site to have that say.

Comment: Do you also have 10 years experience with Swift? (Stack Overflow is a little over 7 years old.)

Comment: Gaining less than a 100 rep per year sounds like very occasional/timid use of SO (or any SE site).

Answer (score 7):

I thought this through once before and it didn't really pan out.

> … restrict the new upvote/downvote on closure to members with a certain reputation level,

Since closing a post is done by a vote, you are essentially asking members to vote on the vote.

The way subjects become off topic is not as *elite* as you think. Questions that are closed can also be opened again, *by a vote.* The meta support site is wide open where folks discuss what is on topic sometimes over years, *subject to the vote.* Dissenting comments are often seen in both the main Q&A and in meta, often years after the fact… and even *those* are escalated by vote.

So sometimes trying to vote on *everything* (even the vote) can be pushed a bit too far.

That's just my opinion.

Cheers,

[image]

Comment: Think you can safely mark it [tag:status-declined] then, no?